# Transcend Jetflash 2GB pendrive not detected properly.No space in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, usb-drive

This is the lsusb -v log for the pendrive. I didn't see it is mounted.

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x058f Alcor Micro Corp.
  idProduct          0x1234 Flash Drive
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

This is dmesg log :

```
[ 9710.384067] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 9710.518065] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=1234
[ 9710.518077] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 9710.518084] usb 1-2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 9710.518091] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
[ 9710.518691] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 9710.520665] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 9711.520937] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 9711.521515] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 9711.527023] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 9730.147507] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 9730.416065] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 9730.944065] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[ 9731.456065] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[ 9731.594148] usb 2-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[ 9731.616149] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=1234
[ 9731.616159] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 9731.616167] usb 2-2: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 9731.616174] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
[ 9731.618324] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 9731.618690] scsi host5: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[ 9732.620240] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 9732.620833] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 9732.631256] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 9749.772165] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 9751.220074] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 9751.354060] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=1234
[ 9751.354072] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 9751.354080] usb 1-1: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 9751.354086] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
[ 9751.354857] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 9751.355433] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 9752.352940] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 9752.353527] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 9752.358383] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I didn't see anything for :

```
sudo fdisk-l
df-h
```

Sometimes pendrives blinks LED and off for a while. I am not able to get where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

from your logs, it seemed alcor trancend jetflash detected as /dev/sdb

assuming that it did not have any partition configured, you can format it with gparted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
gksudo gparted
```